# Accessing values in mapping generated knockout model based on unnamed array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am retrieving Json data from a web api. The data is in the format:

```
[{"CustomerID":1,"CustomerName":"John"},{"CustomerID":2,"CustomerName":"Sally"}]
```

The real data is naturally more complex, but it has the format of an array of items that does not have a "name", e.g., {"customers":[...]}. I can't change the data being passed so this is what I have to live with.

I want to create a knockout model on this data with the mapping plugin and tie it to the view:

```
var vmCustomers = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonObject);
ko.applyBindings(vmPartners);
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to access the data on the HTML-page. I can see that the data has been loaded into the model if I inspect vmCustomers and drill down in _latestValue.

What I want to be able to do in the HTML is the corresponding thing to

```
foreach: customers
```

I can get it working by building up the knockout-model manually and just use .mapping to fill it (or even fill it manually), but I would like to avoid that. What I am looking for is a way to get hold of the top array in the knockout model from the HTML code.

I am very new to knockout so there might be something fundamental that I am missing.

Comment: Where you want bind this in html? To input element may be ?

Comment: For instance I want to bind it an unordered list. If the name of the array had been customers it would have looked something like <ul  data-bind="foreach: customers"><li data-bind="text: CustomerName"></li></ul>

Comment: Have you see this website knockoutjs.com.

Comment: See tutorial section. You will easily find your answer there.

Comment: I read most of the material in the documentation and tutorials several times (and I revisited it again), but I can't find any reference on how to access arrays that are not defined with a name. All the examples I can find have named observableArrays. I am not asking how to get it working. I can easily do that with manually defining the model, but I am trying to avoid it if possible to reduce the javascript code I have to write and maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't fight against KO. Just create a proper viewmodel where you have a `customers` property to hold your data, this is the KO way of doing it. Anyway a viewmodel will be handy in the future when you will have a place to put additional logic/data.

```
var viewModel = { customers: ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonObject); }
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then you can have have your `data-bind="foreach: customers"`  in your view.

However if you don't want to have a viewmodel and you want to bind to an array you can't access it with a name like "customers" you need to reference it with the [current context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html): with using the `$data` property:

```
data-bind="foreach: $data"
```

JS

```
var vmCustomers = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonObject);
ko.applyBindings(vmCustomers);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjZqj/).

Comment: THX! I implemented a variation of what you suggested, which also gives me a proper viewmodel to put logic in. What I did was:

Comment: THX a lot! I implemented a variation of what you suggested. What I did was: function vmCustomers() { var self = this; self.customers = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonObject); } and then of course ko.applyBindings(new vmCustomers());. It gave me very little code, a proper viewmodel as well as a better way of getting to the data from the HTML. Thx again!